# Laravel deleting package with composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I tried to delete [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) from my laravel installation, and it seems I didn't make something right.

What I did so far :

- `composer remove barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`
- I deleted then the references in config/app.php

And I've got an error :

```
[RuntimeException]
Error Output: PHP Fatal error:
Class 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider' not found in 
{mypath}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php on line 146
```

I tried dump-autoload, clear-compiled, but none works.

What did I miss ?

---

22/02/2016 Edit : I also tried to remove ALL the `vendor` folder, then install it again via `composer install`, but I got the error again when the command `php artisan clear-compiled` was run angain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it seems I had played with artisan commands, and the configuration file was cached (*via* `php artisan config:cache`).

I deleted it (in `bootstrap/cache/config.php`) and everything works like a charm, but I also could have used the command `php artisan config:clear` to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for writing the solution! That was the problem on my side as well, no other fixes worked. :)

Answer (score 3):

When you installed Debugbar, after the package was install via composer you needed to add the class to the `providers` array in `config/app.php`. So you need to remove this line from there:

```
Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class
```

If you also register the facade, then you need to remove the following from the `aliases` array from the same file:

```
'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class
```

If you also ran `php artisan vendor:publish` (which is the final step described in the [Installation Section](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar#installation) from the package readme) then you can delete the `config/debugbar.php` file as well, although leaving that configuration file in place will not cause any issues.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "I deleted then the references in app/config", I meant int "config/app.php". My bad ! It has been removed, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Running `php artisan clear-compiled` should have removed all compiled files that are stored in `bootstrap/cache` including the `services.php` file found there, which contains the list of cached service provider classes. You can check and confirm if the files are deleted after the command is run and if not delete them yourself. If the problem persists, do a global search for the text `Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider` in all application files does to see where you may have any remaining references to the provider class (although the bootstrap cache files are the only ones that make sense).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look tonight.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The `php artisan clear-compiled`throws the same error. I looked in the files, and the only mentions (besides the log files) are visible here : http://pastebin.com/TmrspnZu

Answer (score 3):

Marc Brillault's answer is correct. I am adding more clarification to that answer:

I removed debug bar class manually from the catch files. present in (`bootstrap/cache/config.php`).

Steps for How to remove manually class.

```
1.) Open this two files 
   `bootstrap/cache/config.php`
   `config/app.php`

2.) Find this two line and remove It.        
    Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
   'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,

3.) run command `php artisan config:clear`
```

after the following this step check command `php artisan list` is working well.

Comment: Excuse me, how is your answer different from the one I already gave ? You even copy/pasted the first line.

Answer (score 1):

you must:

First. Delete the references to Debugbar in config/app.php

Second. composer remove barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

In that order. If you don't, Laravel get confused ;)

Comment: I forgot to tell that you can  do    

composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar again to get it back to the "installed point" and them remove it, doing those two steps in the right order.

Comment: Thanks, but I had already found the solution to my problem (Which was more specific). However, your comment is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

The best ways you need to do is delete all file manually in all composer files.

Comment: That's not very different from a composer remove, and wouldn't have solved this (specific) problem